# merge two django querysets without changing the order

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I need to do two different filtering to the queryset.
`qs1 = qs.filter(name=value)`
`qs2 = qs.filter(equipment_set__name=value)`

Then I need to connect them without changing the order, just like they were created.

`qs_result = <QuerySet [<qs1 >, <qs2>,]`

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [**`.union(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
qs_result = qs1.union(qs2, all=True)
```

This can yield the same item multiple times. To prevent that, you remove `all=True`:

```
qs_result = qs1.union(qs2)  # without duplicates
```

Comment: Are you sure that the order of the data won't change as if I applied add to an array?

Comment: @Cooler1337: based on some tests I did a few years ago, it retained the order.

Comment: Okay, but if I remove all=True so objects don't repeat, they change order, how do I avoid this?

Comment: @Cooler1337: by not removing `all=True`.

Comment: then the order will definitely change.

Comment: can I do without union? since I need to apply other filters afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use | operator to merge two queries without changing the order of instances in queryset

```
queryset_1 = A.objects.filter(id__in=[2, 5])
queryset_2 = A.objects.filter(id__in=[3, 4])

queryset_3 = queryset_1 | queryset_2
```

You can also filter on it later.

Comment: This *does* change the order. It will for this specific query move to `WHERE id IN (2, 5) OR id in (3, 4)`, so (a) it can return the items in any order; and (b) if items overlap in the two, it will yield these once, so if you would have used `id__in=[2,4,5]` it will return the one with `id=4` once, not twice.